# Android phone for developer

Tags: android, mobile, smartphone

I want to start develop android appliacation, and I want to know wich phone is the most recomended.

Need to support in android version 2.3.
The Sony-Ericsson Xperia X10 Mini can be updated to 2.3?

Thanks

---

Many thanks,
The X8 can be updated to 2.3 android?
I Read that the X8 and the X10 can be updated.
Where can I find guide for update my X8\X10?

I tried to work with the emulator but My application it's low level application.
Because of that I need smartphone to work with the kernel.

Comment: Some possible duplicates:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133296/best-phone-for-doing-android-sw-development

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539074/which-android-phone-to-use-for-development

Comment: Times change and so do phones. The mentioned phones in those links are rather old.

Answer (score 2):

In the end you don't even need a Androidphone to develop. I used the emulator for the first application I wrote in Android and I still do to doublecheck on different Android versions.

Having a phone yourself is much more comfortable, because it's faster and you have the direct feedback, but you would need a phone of every screen-size, screen-density and Android version to achieve the diversity of the emulator.

I wouldn't recommend to buy an Androidphone just for devolping. And getting an Androidphone for private use is something completly else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: No, the X10 Mini can not be updated to Android 2.3. At least not officially.

You don't need an Android phone, if you want to develop applications and games for Android, but I'd personally recommend it anyway. The emulators are often considerably slower than the real deal.

It's also considerably easier to develop on a real phone rather than the emulator, again mainly because it's slow. If your application is working with files and you often need to swap test files, it can also be quite annoying with the emulator, because you need to push one file at a time (someone please correct me if I'm wrong on that one).

Strictly speaking though, it is not a requirement, but I would strongly advise you to do so anyway. The Nexus S would be a good average phone that's easy to develop on, and it's just been updated to Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0), so you'll be covered in that aspect as well.